# Create Notification App in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I want to create a sample project to show notification on click of button then when the user selects it open that activity in my app or open a url on selection of that. I have done something but I'm unable to complete the functionality.

First I am getting error to use this: `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`

If I am not using this I am getting the error on here

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
```

**Activity Code**

```
public class NotificationExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_example);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("Ticker Title")
        .setContentTitle("Content Title")
        .setContentText("Notification content.")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
        noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 
    }
}
```

Why I have to use this:

```
`@SuppressLint("NewApi")`
```

in my code?
I am not getting the notification sound. Please suggest me what changes I have to make in my code.

Comment: why i have to use this @SuppressLint("NewApi") in my code .It is not giving me the notification sound

Comment: @SuppressLint("NewApi") is an annotation used by the Android Lint tool.

Comment: and why i am not getting the notification sound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add sound to your notification, use following short of code.

```
Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(notificationSound);
```

**Full Code**

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                0);
Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setTicker("Ticker Title").setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .setContentText("Notification content.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent);
Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(notificationSound);
Notification noti = builder.build();
noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

`context` is `Application Context` get using `getApplicationContext()`.

**Edit**

To open any link to Browser using Notification, use following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

Pass this intent to your `PendingIntent`

Comment: @chitan how could i open a URL in this when the user opens the notification

Comment: yup actually it might possible i have to open a new activity or a URL when user open this ..so i got the solution for new activity help me how could i open a URL

Comment: have u got any thing for me

Comment: will u see this if u can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529802/how-to-use-scheduler-for-http-request/18530229?noredirect=1#comment27251567_18530229

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

replace

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this);
```

with

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(NotificationExample .this);
```

You can't use **this** reference for context object from a click listener.

Comment: why i have to use this @SuppressLint("NewApi") in my code .It is not giving me the notification sound

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Function**

```
public static void addToNotificationBar(Context mContext,String ticker, String title, String message) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(), 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticker, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, title, message, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Comment: please explain the parameter what i have to pass in this function and on click of button i will call this