# How to use Scheduler for Http Request

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I want to create a application in Android that once it is installed in the deive.It send a HTTP rrequest in every 5 mins .After getting the response it shows the notification .How could i do this .

**Activity Code**

```
public class AutoNotification extends Activity {
    String url="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_notification);
        postHttpRequest("Test","Test");

    }

    public  void postHttpRequest(String userId,String pass){
        RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(AutoNotification.this);
        String AppResponse = null;
        try {
            url = "";
            Log.d("URL", url);
            AppResponse = reqClient.execute().get();
            String status = "200";
            Log.d("Status recived", status);

            if(status.equals("200")){
                autoNotify();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception Occured", "Exception is "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void autoNotify(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AutoNotification.this, 0, intent, 0);
        Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker("Test Title").setContentTitle("Content Test")
            .setContentText("Test Notification.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(notificationSound);
        Notification noti = builder.build();    
        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

    }
}
```

Now how could i call this on every 5 min and show the notification.Please help me this

**Edit**
Thanks @chintan for Suggestion .i have done this :

```
public class AutoNotification extends Activity {
    String url="";
    private Timer refresh = null;
    private final long refreshDelay = 5 * 1000;
    SendHttpRequestThread sendHttpRequestThread; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_notification);

        sendHttpRequestThread = new SendHttpRequestThread("Test","Test");
        sendHttpRequestThread.start();

    }



    public  void postHttpRequest(String userId,String pass){
        RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(AutoNotification.this);
        String AppResponse = null;
        try {
            url = "";
            Log.d("URL", url);
            AppResponse = reqClient.execute(url).get();
            String status = "200";
            Log.d("Status recived", status);

            if(status.equals("200")){
                autoNotify();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception Occured", "Exception is "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void autoNotify(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AutoNotification.this, 0, intent, 0);
        Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker("Test Title").setContentTitle("Content Test")
            .setContentText("Test Notification.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(notificationSound);
        Notification noti = builder.build();    
        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

    }

    class SendHttpRequestThread extends Thread {

        boolean sendHttpRequest;
        String userId;
        String pass;

        public SendHttpRequestThread(String str1, String str2) {
            this.userId = str1;
            this.pass = str2;
            sendHttpRequest = true;
        }

        public void stopSendingHttpRequest() {
            sendHttpRequest = false;
        }

        protected void onStop() {
            sendHttpRequestThread.stopSendingHttpRequest();
            super.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (sendHttpRequest) {
                postHttpRequest(userId, pass);

                SystemClock.sleep(refreshDelay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created one Custom Thread class which will sleep for 5 secs.

```
public class SendHttpRequestThread extends Thread {

    boolean sendHttpRequest;
    String userId;
    String pass;

    public SendHttpRequestThread(String str1, String str2) {
        this.userId = str1;
        this.pass = str2;
        sendHttpRequest = true;
    }

    public void stopSendingHttpRequest() {
        sendHttpRequest = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (sendHttpRequest) {
            postRequest(userId, pass);
            //add code here to execute in background thread
            autoNotify();
            SystemClock.sleep(delayMillis);
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't implemented all code, you need to put inside `while` loop. Here `delayMillis` is integer value holding `5000` as `sleep()` takes input of mili seconds.

To execute this `Thread`, write following code.

```
sendHttpRequestThread = new SendHttpRequestThread("Test","Test");
sendHttpRequestThread.start();
```

To stop this `Thread`, write following code.

```
sendHttpRequestThread.stopSendingHttpRequest();
```

If you want to stop this thread when activity is stopped, then write like below.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    sendHttpRequestThread.stopSendingHttpRequest();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: from where i will call my postHttpRequest () i am not getting please explain it more.One every 5 mins i have to send http request and after getting the response from the request i have notify it

Comment: updated my code will check it once and update it if any issue .thanks

Comment: @Rahul, I used `sendHttpRequest` and `autoNotify()` in thread. This will not check your response. As you have checked in your method. So i am removing that code of `autoNotify` from thread. This will remain in your http method. When there is response code 200, will notify you. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36536/discussion-between-rahul-and-chintan-rathod)

Comment: ANy UI part like once get installed don't want to show any kind of UI @chitan i want to discuss with u ..i need u r suggestion ...and u r code is now working fine for me thanks alot

Comment: i want to create a app .that will notify my user that u have to do this task.This msg will be sent by server .So i want to know could i implement this.Suppose a user have booked a ticket from y app.Now i want to send him the notification that today is u r travel date how could i implement this.What i need to this

Comment: Hm.. i suggested dude.. GCM. Go for it.. You will get your answer. Google Cloud Messaging.. One of most powerful push notification.

Comment: Last question so from this if i send the notification after selecting the notification i will be able to start my activity

Comment: Ya of course you can.. But GCM is not such easy as you think.. :P You need to build a server for that and registration id will also take place.. So first just try that. I will definitely help you. Don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code in onCreate() method

```
private Timer refresh = null;
    private final long refreshDelay = 5 * 1000;

            if (refresh == null) { // start the refresh timer if it is null
                refresh = new Timer(false);

                Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ refreshDelay);
                refresh.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             postHttpRequest("Test","Test");
                            refresh();
                        }
                    }, date, refreshDelay);
```

Comment: refresh () what is this ??

Comment: refresh is timer class  object

Comment: this is the error it is showing The method refresh() is undefined for the type new TimerTask(){}